# Why I cannot set class alias in controller's action in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2, alias

In my `SiteController` -> `actionLogin`, I am trying to set class alias of class `LoginForm`. Below are failed attempt

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    class_alias('LoginForm', 'lf_alias');
    class_alias('LoginForm', 'lf_alias', true);

    class_alias('common\models\LoginForm', 'common\models\lf_alias');
    class_alias('common\models\LoginForm', 'common\models\lf_alias', true);
    class_alias('common\models\LoginForm', 'lf_alias', true);

    $model = new lf_alias();
    // ... rest of the code
```

I am getting following error

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'frontend\controllers\lf_alias' not found
```

I am using Yii2 advanced template

Comment: why do you use class aliases?

Comment: I am trying to learn class_alias,  aliasing auto loaded class

Comment: it'd be better to avoid to use them at all and to stick to namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class_alias('common\models\LoginForm', 'anyname');
```

so you have to call it like

```
$model = new \anyname();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, throws the error mentioned in question

Comment: @SohelAhmedM I just now tested it also, it works fine.

Comment: Which PHP and Yii version are you using?

Comment: PHP: 5.5.12 Yii2: 2.0.6

Comment: sure you put back slash "\" before alias name, while creating new object ?

Comment: Oh yes, I missed backslash, thanks, Once alias is made, PHP will find it in global namespace. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can set namespace\class alias with operator **use**:

```
use common\models\LoginForm as lf_alias
```

Comment: Definitely this is a fine approach, but not exact answer to my question